# CSS - Does a relative element needs height?

Tags: css

I've heard that **if** we have a *absolute element* **as** *child of a relative element*, the *relative element* will **never** display the contents inside, **unless**, a s*pecific height is declared*.

But this assumption must be wrong:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b wrapper-to-contain-floats">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste dicta modi natus iure temporibus, asperiores consequuntur at explicabo aperiam aliquid, rem eligendi corporis possimus veritatis maxime, praesentium reiciendis! Debitis, illo!</p>
    </div>
</div>


.a {
 position: relative;   
}

.b{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}

.wrapper-to-contain-floats {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/buc87c37/

Why do we see the paragraph contents?

Can I have some help?

Comment: Basically those assumptions only work for the visual elements like divs span.. Those doesnt work for these kind of Modulus elments, the data in these elements must br displayed.

Comment: Sorry. Don't follow. What assumptions only work for the visual elements? If we replace the fiddle with div instead of p the effect is the same. And the contents still appear. Care to clarify please? Ty.

Comment: Okay, visual elememts means everytag in html. Text is the ultimate end quantity which should be displayed. That is if you remove any tag inside that b and write something that something will be printed ANYWAY. Text wont care if it is absolute or not

Comment: Got it. Thank you. That solves problem 1). So, there's no way with CSS to have the relative element to adjust to it's absolute child contents?

Comment: Nope, `position:absolute` takes the element out of the flow of the document.

Comment: When absolute is used then that element stays absolute with its docunent windie. Relative is for its parent

Comment: TheDarkKnight I said I got what you have explained, and I upvoted, but I haven't totally get it yet. I have place a paragraph inside a div, and that paragraph styles shouldn't be considered no? God, this is getting hard to catch: https://jsfiddle.net/buc87c37/1/

Comment: To further illustrate, you can see the contents in your first example because the overflow of `.a` is visible. Look where the background of `.a` stops in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/buc87c37/2/). With the overflow of `.a` hidden, like in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/buc87c37/3/), the content is not visible. Here is  another [visual example](https://jsfiddle.net/buc87c37/4/) showing that the absolutely positioned `.b` is removed from the flow of the document and does not expand the height of `.a`.

Comment: Your para is inside the red container so it aquires red property. Absolute wont stop the p from this.

Comment: I'm surprised you understand what TheDarkKnight said. "Modulus elments", "visual elememts means everytag in html", "Text is the ultimate end quantity", "docunent windie". WAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "if we have a absolute element as child of a relative element, the relative element will never display the contents inside, unless, a specific height is declared."

Haha, what? I'm eager to know the guy who said this, especially if it's a college professor or a respected web design blogger. I love feeling superior.

I will try to provide you with a better guideline for the rel/abs funny behaviors. "When an element is absolutely-positioned, it does not affect the total content area of the div it is contained in".

Normally, divs are not given a height - they don't need one. By default, `height: auto` expands their height out to the sum of the height of any content in child or sub-child elements. But this doesn't happen with `position: absolute`. If you inspect that JSFiddle, you will see that `.a` has an actual height of **0**. That is uncommon, but as it turns out, it doesn't actually prevent the content from appearing, because the default overflow behavior is "`overflow: visible`". You can see the effect better if you give `.a` a border.

Normally, the entire expansive nature of vertically-scrolling webpages depends on the behavior of automatic content height calculation. As a result, absolute positioning makes sense in the following scenarios:

- There is only one of the element you want to position absolutely
- You can know the minimum height of an element beforehand, and know that there will be space for the absolutely positioned element inside of it (random example: A close button in a top corner)
- JavaScript is constantly re-calculating the position/size of the element, and takes responsibility for its proper sizing and positioning

But if you have, say, a vertical series of form elements, that is something that should really use normal document layout. From preliminary inspection of your checkout form, I can't really find any aspects of the layout that would require absolute positioning. You should be able to `display: none` any steps that should not be active at the time, and they will then not affect the layout of the current step.

Comment: the reason why we need to have position absolute is because, if you don't have position absolute, and you hit NEXT, you will notice that step2 will start BELOW, instead of side by side.

Comment: Wohoooo!! https://jsfiddle.net/buc87c37/2/ Ok... thank you all. Field of study for me. :)

Comment: Ah, okay. I did not actually try submitting, given personal paranoia. I'm guessing it's a side-to-side transition? That should be doable with the CSS `transform: translateX(100%)`, transitioning to `transform: translateX(0)`. In fact, I did something like that in a webapp I worked on.